# how to concat strings on PDI?

Tags: time, etl, aggregation, pentaho, kettle

I have a PDI (Kettle) job that populates a dim_time table with the columns hour, minute and second.

I'd like to create a fourth (aggregated) column that contains a representation of the given time like HH:MM:SS, how can I do that on PDI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways of doing that. If you want this fourth column as a string you can go for this "point-and-click only" solution:

Insert a `Calculator` step and insert fields as follow:

---

- **New Field:** h1
- **Calculation:** Create a copy of field A
- **Field A:** hour
- **Field B:**
- **Value Type:** String
- **Remove:** Y
- **Conversion Mask:** 00:

---

- **New Field:** m1
- **Calculation:** Create a copy of field A
- **Field A:** minute
- **Field B:**
- **Value Type:** String
- **Remove:** Y
- **Conversion Mask:** 00:

---

- **New Field:** s1
- **Calculation:** Create a copy of field A
- **Field A:** second
- **Field B:**
- **Value Type:** String
- **Remove:** Y
- **Conversion Mask:** 00 *(Attention here, there's no ":")*

---

- **New Field:** t1
- **Calculation:** A + B
- **Field A:** h1
- **Field B:** m1
- **Value Type:** String
- **Remove:** Y
- **Conversion Mask:**

---

- **New Field:** time_string
- **Calculation:** A + B
- **Field A:** t1
- **Field B:** s1
- **Value Type:** String
- **Remove:** N *(Attention here, choose N otherwise your desired field won't be added to stream)*
- **Conversion Mask:**

---

And that should be all you need. Probably there are methods using javascript, but you'll need to code and find the right string formatting functions.

Comment: thank you for your solution. After I posted this question, I tried a JavaScript approach to the solution and it did work as I expected. Even though I'm not using it, yours is quite an elegant solution as well!